# object tag keeps downloading

Tags: javascript, html, svg, webserver

I have an  tag in a web page that is being fed an SVG file with the "data" attribute. All is well when running local and the file is being rendered inside the object. Even on a test site that i have set up all is well.

When i uploaded my site using GoDaddy, and when i try to access that page, the browser is asking if i want to save the SVG file. It is being treated like a downloadable file.

The object tag is as such:

```
<object id="theSVG" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

And the SVG file is being passed using Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('theSVG').setAttribute('data', '/theFile.svg');
```

I tried placing the data attribute directly inside the object tag and skip the javascript step but without luck.

I just do not understand why this is happening on GoDaddy and not on ParallelPlesk. Could there be any setting on the web server that i missed to set?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I added this code in the web.config file:

```
<remove fileExtension=".svg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
```

Thanks @RobertLongson for the heads up.